# Como copiar arquivos de um container Docker para a Área de trabalho local

Tags: docker

Estou tentando copiar um arquivo de dentro de um container do Docker usando o seguinte comando:

```
docker cp container_id:app.txt ~/desktop/app.txt
```

Mas ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
invalid output path: directory "C:\\Users\\my_user\\desktop\\~\\desktop" does not exist
```

O que eu quero é copiar esse arquivo `app.txt` para a área de trabalho, então tentei usar a lógica do `cd ~/desktop`, que pegaria o usuário atual e entraria na pasta `desktop`, mas não funcionou.

Existe algum jeito certo de se fazer isso?

Comment: não seria mais fácil copiar para uma pasta qualquer e depois mover para o desktop? esses caminhos do windows as vezes se resolvem

Answer (score 2):

Pelo erro, parece que você já está no diretório do Desktop (pelo caminho do erro
`C:\\Users\\my_user\\desktop\\~\\desktop`).

Só um ponto já bastaria:

```
docker cp container_id:app.txt .
```

Comment: Um comentário explicando sobre o voto negativo me ajudaria muito a melhorar a resposta.

Comment: A palavra **haters** responde a seu comentário? Pois basta ler com atenção a pergunta e constatar em path fornecido pelo AP `"C:\\Users\\my_user\\desktop\\~\\desktop"` que ele já está na pasta desktop, assim confirmando a sua resposta.